# PHP - Packing widgets into the fewest number of boxes, plus minimum order quantity

Tags: php, algorithm

The problem is this:

A company supplies widgets in a set of pack sizes:

- 250
- 500
- 1000
- 2000
- 5000

Customers can order any number of widgets, but the following rules apply:

- Only whole packs can be sent and …
- No more widgets than necessary should be sent and …
- The fewest packs possible should be sent

Some examples showing the number of widgets ordered and the required pack quantities and sizes to correctly fulfill the order:

- 1 (1 x 250)
- 251 (1 x 500)
- 501 (1 x 500 and 1 x 250)
- 12001 (2 x 5000 and 1 x 2000 and 1 x 250)

I’ve looked at some algorithms (greedy coin change, LAFF, etc.) as these seem to provide similar solutions, but can’t seem to see how to adapt them to the above.

For example:

```
<?php

function countWidgets($amount) 
{ 
    $packs = array(5000, 2000, 1000, 500, 
                  250); 
    $packCounter = array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0); 
    $packsCount = count($packs);

    // loop packs
    for ($i = 0; $i < $packsCount; $i++)  
    { 
        if ($amount >= $packs[$i]) 
        { 
            $packCounter[$i] = intval($amount /  
                                      $packs[$i]); 
            $amount = $amount -  
                      $packCounter[$i] *  
                      $packs[$i]; 
        } 
    }

    // if remainder
    if ($amount > 0) {
        // and if smallest pack size populated
        if ($packCounter[4] == 1) {
            // clear smallest pack size
            $packCounter[4] = 0;
            // increment next biggest pack size
            $packCounter[3] += 1;
        } else {
            // increment smallest pack size
            $packCounter[4] +=1;
        }
    }


    // Print packs 
    echo ("Pack ->"."\n"); 
    for ($i = 0; $i < $packsCount; $i++)  
    { 
        if ($packCounter[$i] != 0)  
        { 
            echo ($packs[$i] . " : " . 
                  $packCounter[$i] . "\n"); 
        } 
    } 
} 

$amount = 251; 
countWidgets($amount);
```

Comment: I don't see what the problem is here? You start by trying the biggest pack, until there are fewer widgets left than the size of that pack. Then you move to a smaller pack, and so on, until the smallest pack. If there are some ordered widget left, after all of this, you add one smallest pack. That's it. If you can do it by hand, then you can certainly program it.

Comment: Can you confirm that the code is complete and that it functions correctly? If so, I recommend that you [edit] to add a summary of the testing (ideally as reproducible unit-test code).  If it's not working, it isn't ready for review (see [help/on-topic]) and the question may be deleted.

Answer (score 2):

OK, I agree that this is a bit harder than I assumed yesterday. You basically have two opposing demands:

1. No more widgets than necessary should be sent.
2. The fewest packs possible should be sent.

You **cannot** fulfill both. So if I tried to send 1200 widgets, rule 2 says I should send a pack of 2000, however, rule 1 says I should send 2 packs: one of 1000 and one of 250. Which rule should prevail?

I chose that rule 1 should prevail in the solution below. The reason is that no customer wants more widgets than absolutely necessary.

```
$packSizes = [ 250,
               500,
              1000,
              2000,
              5000];

function optimizePacks($packSizes,$number)
{
    rsort($packSizes);
    $requiredPacks = array_fill_keys($packSizes,0);
    foreach ($packSizes as $size) {
        $packs = floor($number/$size);
        if ($packs > 0) {
            $requiredPacks[$size] = $packs;
            $number -= $packs*$size;
        }
    }
    if ($number > 0) $requiredPacks[min($packSizes)]++;
    return $requiredPacks;
}

$packs = optimizePacks($packSizes,6666);

print_r($packs);
```

This will work for any array of pack sizes and any number of widgets. The output of this code is:

> Array (
>       [5000] => 1
>       [2000] => 0
>       [1000] => 1
>       [500] => 1
>       [250] => 1 )

Which is one pack more than rule 2 would demand (one of 5000 and two of 1000). It would, of course, be possible to let rule 2 prevail, but I cannot fulfill both rules.

Comment: You missed a rule `Only whole packs can be sent`  The other 2 rules do not compete, you can send `No more widgets than necessary should be sent.` and `The fewest packs possible should be sent`  For example `1200` would not be more then `necessary` and the `2000` unit box would be `fewest packs`  - See the `Only whole packs` is the real competing rule (against, fewest packs)  if that makes sense, well it makes sense to me.  The `more then necessary` rule is actually half a rule So it can be ignored without the `Only whole packs` rule.

Comment: Sending 1200 parts in a box that "can" hold 2000 is not sending more parts then necessary, it's sending the necessary parts in a bigger box.  I built something like this before, I thought of the game [Mancala](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mancala)

Comment: This almost works, except you need to calculate the actual minimum number to fullfil the order first, then optimsie it, so an order of 251 widgets is actually an order for 500, this way you will fulfill all 3 criteria, I built an example here https://wallys-widgets.tilt.ninja/

Answer (score 1):

Here is one using a while loop and simple subtaction:

```
$packSizes = [250,500,1000,2000,5000];
$number = 3000;              

function optimizePacks($packSizes,$number)
{
    //insure packs are in decending order
    rsort($packSizes);
    //create a default array
    $results = array_fill_keys($packSizes, 0);

    while($number > 0){
        echo "---------- $number ----------\n";

        foreach($packSizes as $size){
            if($size <= $number) break;
        }
        ++$results[$size];
        $number -= $size;
    }
    return $results;
}

$tests = [
    1,      // (1 x 250)
    251,    // (1 x 500)
    501,    // (1 x 500 and 1 x 250)
    12001   // (2 x 5000 and 1 x 2000 and 1 x 250)

];

foreach($tests as $test) print_r(optimizePacks($packSizes,$test));
```

Output

```
---------- 1 ----------
Array
(
    [5000] => 0
    [2000] => 0
    [1000] => 0
    [500] => 0
    [250] => 1
)
---------- 251 ----------
---------- 1 ----------
Array
(
    [5000] => 0
    [2000] => 0
    [1000] => 0
    [500] => 0
    [250] => 2 //deviates from your example output (see below)
)
---------- 501 ----------
---------- 1 ----------
Array
(
    [5000] => 0
    [2000] => 0
    [1000] => 0
    [500] => 1
    [250] => 1
)
---------- 12001 ----------
---------- 7001 ----------
---------- 2001 ----------
---------- 1 ----------
Array
(
    [5000] => 2
    [2000] => 1
    [1000] => 0
    [500] => 0
    [250] => 1
)
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0ad57a353b8ba28e6673a82e47791eeb76be9dc6)

These 2 examples are at odds with each other

```
251,    // (1 x 500)
501,    // (1 x 500 and 1 x 250)
```

The first one you make one incomplete `500` part box

The second one you make a 500 (complete box) and an extra 250 with one part.

So the question is, why is the first one only 1 box as it should be 250 x 2 boxes. Conversely why is the second 2 boxes when it could be 1000 x 1 boxes.

So either you fit them in the smallest box that can contain them with the extra overflowing. Or you put them in complete boxes and put the remainder in the smallest box.

**UPDATE**

```
If you want the reverse I came up with this:

$packSizes = [250,500,1000,2000,5000];

function optimizePacks($packSizes,$number)
{
    //insure packs are in ascending order
    sort($packSizes);
    //create a default array
    $results = array_fill_keys($packSizes, 0);

    while($number > 0){
        echo "---------- $number ----------\n";

        foreach($packSizes as $size){
            if($size >= $number) break;
        }

        ++$results[$size];
        $number -= $size;
    }
    return $results;
}

$tests = [
    1,      // (1 x 250)
    251,    // (1 x 500)
    501,    // (1 x 500 and 1 x 250)
    12001   // (2 x 5000 and 1 x 2000 and 1 x 250)

];

foreach($tests as $test) print_r(optimizePacks($packSizes,$test));
```

Output

```
---------- 1 ----------
Array
(
    [250] => 1
    [500] => 0
    [1000] => 0
    [2000] => 0
    [5000] => 0
)
---------- 251 ----------
Array
(
    [250] => 0
    [500] => 1
    [1000] => 0
    [2000] => 0
    [5000] => 0
)
---------- 501 ----------
Array
(
    [250] => 0
    [500] => 0
    [1000] => 1  //deviates from your example output
    [2000] => 0
    [5000] => 0
)
---------- 12001 ----------
---------- 7001 ----------
---------- 2001 ----------
Array
(
    [250] => 0
    [500] => 0
    [1000] => 0
    [2000] => 0
    [5000] => 3  //deviates from your example output
)
```

This also points out how the last example is at odds with this way.  Which is to fit the most parts in the smallest size box.  This may be a bigger box but it will not overflow.  For example it wont pick 5000 for 1 part.

I used a pretty nice trick with the foreach in the above code, that let me simplify it greatly.

This only works if you sort it ASC, because if we don't find a box that can hold the full number, the last iteration leaves `$size` at the Max value in the array (its the last one after all).  Which is exactly what we want because then we subtract that from `$number` and repeat the process.

However if we do find a box that can contain all the parts, we simply exit (break) the foreach loop.  This will be the smallest box that can fit all the parts (naturally).  And we also subtract this which will leave `$number` at `<= 0` and break the while loop which completes the function and returns the results.

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/819b718d62c299823a9ceff8be4137ede5ed187a)

If you really want them (the sizes, compare the 2 results in my examples) in the other order, we can either send them in that order and build the default first, or sort one way build the default then reverse the array (which should be faster then sort).

```
function optimizePacks($packSizes,$number)
{
    //insure packs are in decending order
    rsort($packSizes);
    //create a default array (baking in the order)
    $results = array_fill_keys($packSizes, 0);
    //flip the order
    $packSizes = array_reverse($packSizes);


    while($number > 0){
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ca83f122677c0847861bab94cd77b0a1d7928b31)

**Summery**

Essentially you can't have both of these (or your mixed examples) without a whole lot of conditional statements that would violate using a dynamic array of sizes.  You could do that with fixed sizes and special if conditions, for example.  This is because your inconsistently applying your rules.

Hope it helps, I get some weird enjoyment out of figuring this stuff out... lol